# Disable AJAX on only home page with jQuery Mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am looking for a way to simply disable AJAX on ONLY the home page in my project. I am using MVC so there are links to the home page in many areas. I want AJAX for the entire site however not when loading the home page. The reason is because I am using a script to setup the UI dynamically, it contains objects and those objects load when the page loads as a hard refresh but no when jQuery Mobile transitions to the page.  I am looking for a solution where I can add a Script to just the home page to disable AJAX whenever it is referenced.  But still have AJAX for the rest of the solution.  Its a very unique situation but I haven't found anything that could prevent ONE page from being loaded through AJAX. Does anyone know?

if I could I would like to do something like this only on the home page

```
<script>
$(document).bind(function(){
    [some call to disable this page from being loaded with AJAX]
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing exists. Think of AJAX like a little mini-browser: if the URL returns a response, it can access it. However, it *might* be possible to branch on the existence of a request header in your Home action and return something like a 403 Forbidden if an "AJAXy" request header is detected.

jQuery, for example, sends an `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header along with its request. If this header is present, the request most likely came from an AJAX method in jQuery (or other libraries that potentially use the same methodology). You can also pass your own custom headers with the AJAX request, if you want. However, all of this is implementation-specific, so it pretty much depends on all developers on your team doing things a certain way. For example, if someone used a standard JavaScript XHR object to make the request, then the `X-Requested-With` header would be absent. Or, if you used a custom header, every developer would need to pass that header every time, or again, the logic would break down.

If your business rules say that the home page shouldn't be requested via AJAX, the best way to handle that is at a *business* level, i.e. policy. Anything you try to in the actual code could easily be worked around.